BPMN Symbol Standardization
I'm getting started with BPMN and use a drawing tool (draw.io) that has a set of BPMN symbols included. There are some gateways that I could not find anywhere else.
I could not find them in the BPMN specification (2.0). How strict BPMN regarding this specification?
And are those two valid BPMN symbols? Have you seen them anywhere else?

Thanks for any input

As far as I know, there is no equivalent for the above symbols in BPMN 2.0, there is an event gateway but the notation is quite different and the purpose thereof.
Refer BPMN reference from Camunda and Activiti 6 reference for some general information for different events.
The above notations are perhaps specific to draw.io, I am not sure.

That is correct, neither of the symbols is standard BPMN element nor does it seem to make much sense. While you often do have the situation where your gateway path is chosen by the type of message received, but what typically is done in cuch cases is an event based gateway followed by message catching events witch different messages caught on different paths outgoing from the gateway. Additional benefit is the ability to add also other event types, e.g. timed event (to handle eg. timeout/offer expiry etc.)
